# Need to loop through column AI and if cell is not empty then look look in column W and move number in next column

Tags: excel, vba

[image][HERE IS A NEW IMAGE HOPEFULLY SHOWING WHAT HAS TO MOVE AND WHERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W9dt.jpg)'Here is a sample of some code I have been trying.

```
sub
For Each cel In Range("W2:W1000")
    If cel.Value = "Credit Adj W/O To Collection" AND
    Range("AI2:AI1000").Cells.Value > ""  THEN
    cel.Offset(0,-9).value =
end sub
```

Basically I need to look in column W for a specific text and if it is found move the number in the next column, col X over to column Y in the same row as the data in column AI, but in column Y.  My issue is the amount of rows it has to move up is different based on where the data is in column AI. See screenshot

[image: Screeshot]

All of you have been a great help but it is still not moving any numbers.  I added another screenshot.  I need to look for the text in blue, if found move the amount in column X two columns right and up to the row that has a value in column AI.  That gap could be different for each entry, as shown in the screen shot. could be 2 or 4 or 5, just depends on Column AI.  Also first entry may not always start in the same row as it does here.  The spot in column W and AI may be different throughout the spreadsheet.  Hope this helps define my purpose a little.

Everyone has had great ideas but still not working, logic in answers makes sense but it is not grabbing any of the data much less move it.  Not sure what is up.

Comment: Might be useful to highlight the destination cells for each of the values, so it's clearer what you want to do with this code.

Comment: Can you share a more accurate practical example for one case, e.g. `AI4 = N83.11` (not blank) then go to `W4` and check for a value. If it is matched then take `X4` and write it to `Y8`. This is probably wrong, but improve on this and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Are you sure that `Credit Adj W/O To Collection` does not contain any spaces or invisible characters at the end? In any cell use the formula `=Len(W5)`. The result should be `28`. Or use `=W5="Credit Adj W/O To Collection"` which should result in `TRUE`.

Comment: Bingo they all had trailing spaces, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```vb
Sub tester()
    
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, rw As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'always use an explicit sheet reference
    
    For Each c In ws.Range("W2:W1000").Cells
        Set rw = c.EntireRow  'the whole row for the cell
        If c.Value = "Credit Adj W/O To Collection" And _
                      IsNumeric(rw.Columns("X").Value) Then
            'copy the value to Col Y in the row above which has a value in Col AI
            ws.Cells(rw.Columns("AI").End(xlUp).Row, "Y").Value = rw.Columns("X").Value
            rw.Columns("X").ClearContents ' clear the "X" value
        
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not work, the value in the green row in column x did not move.  The value in in the row matching the column AI criteria did not change.  I hope I am describing what I need well enough.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Did any row pass the `If...Then` tests?  Did you try debugging by putting a breakpoint inside the `If Then` ?

Comment: No, could not see any data or values being past through variables when debugging

Comment: Based on your comments here an on the other answer, it seems like something is different between what you described and what you have.  Maybe you can share a worksheet with the same layout but with dummy data, so we can confirm?

Comment: The code works on my end and is similar to my code, except that mine allows any value in column `X` and doesn't delete it after copying to `Y` and it 'looks' first in column `AI` and then in column `W`. Your logic was kind of my first idea, but I couldn't figure out the `End(xlUp)` part at that moment when the double `Do Loop` idea came to mind.

Comment: Not working no matter what I try, but thanks for the help.  Debugging is not showing anything stored in the variables as I go through it.  Frustrated

Comment: We can help if you can share a simple example of your sheet, otherwise there's not much else we can do.

Answer (score 2):

### A Tricky Column Update

1. Loop (`r = r + 1`) from the first row to the last row (the latter calculated in column `W`).
2. When column `AI` is not blank, write the row number to a variable (`rFound`).
3. Continue looping (`r = r + 1`). When column `W` is equal to the string `Credit Adj W/O To Collection`, write the value in column `X` of the current row to column `Y` of the row kept in the variable (`rFound`).
4. Continue looping (`r = r + 1`) by alternating between steps 2. and 3. until the last row.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateInsAmt()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const rStart As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim rLast As Long: rLast = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim r As Long: r = rStart
    Dim rFound As Long
    
    Do
        If Len(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "AI").Value)) > 0 Then ' is not blank
            rFound = r
            r = r + 1 ' it can't be in the same row
            Do
                If StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "W").Value), _
                        "Credit Adj W/O To Collection", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    ws.Cells(rFound, "Y").Value = ws.Cells(r, "X").Value
                    Exit Do ' value found and written so stop looping ...***
                'Else ' value not found ...
                End If
                r = r + 1 ' ... so incremenet row
            Loop Until r > rLast
        ' Else ' is blank ...
        End If
        r = r + 1 ' ... so increment row, ...*** and increment row
    Loop Until r > rLast
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope didn't seem to work, but thanks for the help.  I really think I am describing it wrong.  Based on the screenshot here is what I am looking for.   I need to see in column W what is in row 5 because it contains "Credit Adj W/O To Collection" then take the value in that row, in column X and place it in column Y in the row that matches column AI row 4 because column AI row 4 has a value, can be any value.  Now the same has to be done for W11 because it contains the same text.  But I can't just do an offset because the amount moved up is based on the row the value is in in column AI

Comment: That is exactly what the code does. Could you read once more through the steps at the beginning of my post? Maybe you can spot what's wrong with my logic. It is different but I think it does what you need. Also, did you check that the worksheet is in the workbook containing this code and its tab name is `Sheet1` (modify if necessary) and that the first data row is row 4? Could you share what exactly is happening when running the code? Also, note that I have modified the code a few times so try to copy it once more.

Comment: The tab name is correct but the data may not always start in row 4 it depends on when the loop hits the correct text in column W.  Then that is when you have to take the amount in the next column and move it up to row Z (not Y as I said before) and in the row based on if there is something in the cell in column AI.  Thanks for the help so far.  I just added another screenshot that may help

Comment: I guess you replace `Y` with `Z` and determine the first row where `AI` has a potential value. I think it still is row `4`.

Comment: Changed everything and still not working, getting frustrated, thanks again for all the help. When I step through it is not showing anything in the variables, not sure why this is not working, looks right to me.